# The base point of the Tate circle in motivic homotopy theory

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to learn some motivic homotopy theory from Voevodsky’s Nordfjordeid Lectures but met a problem at the beginning. In the second to last paragraph of page 3 (or page 149 in the published book), the author said that

> The Tate circle $S^1_t$ is the space $\mathbb{A}^1\setminus0$, pointed by the global section given by the identity.

I don't understand the second half of this sentence. By his definition (see the second paragraph in the same page)

> A pointed space consists of a space $X$ together with a map $x\colon \operatorname{Spec}(k)\rightarrow X.$

So to give the pointed Tate circle, we should specify some map $x\colon\operatorname{Spec}(k)\rightarrow \mathbb{A}^1\setminus0=\operatorname{Spec}(k[x,x^{-1}]),$ or a $k$-algebra homomorphism $k[x,x^{-1}]\rightarrow k.$ I cannot see what this has to do with the ''global section given by the identity''. Could someone tell me where my understanding goes wrong?

Comment: I don't actually know but it sounds like the author thinks of the punctured affine line as the multiplicative group (scheme) , the identity element being the closed point $1$, i.e. given by $x\mapsto 1$. The global section they allude to is $x-1$.

Comment: @Douglas Molin is right. The base point of $\mathbb{G}_m$ which one uses in motivic homotopy theory is the point $1$.

Comment: I have understood. Thank you guys.